# Lodash re-assign array of objects to build a tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Is there a short way to re-assign array that consists of objects into a new one. I want to use Lodash library and can't figure out how to split it inside and concatenate. I need this to build a tree using jstree library

I have something like this:

```
 [
      {
        'text':'parent 1',
        'children': [
          {
            'text':'children 3'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 2',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 3',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 1',
        'children': [
          {
            'text':'children 1',
            'children': []
          },
          {
            'text':'children 2',
            'children': []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And I want to have the next after transforming

```
[
  {
    'text':'parent 2',
    'children': []
  },
  {
    'text':'parent 3',
    'children': []
  },
  {
    'text':'parent 1',
    'children': [
      {
        'text':'children 1',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'children 2',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'children 3'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to combine all objects if 'text' is the same and concatenate their children.

The nested level may be as much as possible, no restriction.

```
[
  {
    'text':'parent 1',
    'children': [
      {
        'text':'children 2',
        'children': [
          {
            'text':'parent 3',
            'children': [
              {
                'text':'parent 4',
                'children': [
                  ...
                ]
              },
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: the best way is to create function to add an element one by one to the tree and return the result tree for each step. 
But before inserting, you need to check the full tree you have at the current step, (starts empty), compare with all the elements existent in the tree, parents and children.(resistivity maybe?)
You can start by the leafs (last children) or the parents, both methods have their own tricks.

Comment: Could you please post the output you need?

Comment: @Nidhin Yes, I've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to combine objects with the same 'text' and remove duplicates, one solution using lodash could be:

```js
var d = [{
  'text': 'parent 1',
  'children': []
}, {
  'text': 'parent 2',
  'children': []
}, {
  'text': 'parent 3',
  'children': []
}, {
  'text': 'parent 1',
  'children': [{
    'text': 'children 1',
    'children': []
  }, {
    'text': 'children 2',
    'children': []
  }]
}];

var res = _.reduce(d, (memo, o) => {
  var already = _.find(memo, o1 => o.text === o1.text);
  return already ? (already.children = already.children.concat(o.children), memo) : memo.concat(o);
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This solution doesn't cover building a tree of more than two levels though.

**UPDATE**

Supposing the structure of your array would represent that of a tree: each "level" represents a level of the tree and objects in the same level in the array are in the same level in the array, a possible solution using recursion could be:

```js
var tree = [{
  'text': 'A',
  'children': [{
    'text': 'A.1',
    'children': [{
      'text': 'A.1.1',
      'children': [{
        'text': 'A.1.1.1',
        'children': [{
          'text': 'A.1.1.1.1'
        }]
      }, {
        'text': 'A.1.1.1',
        'children': [{
          'text': 'A.1.1.1.2'
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    'text': 'A.2',
    'children': [{
      'text': 'A.2.1',
      'children': [{
        'text': 'A.2.1.1',
        'children': []
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  'text': 'B',
  'children': []
}, {
  'text': 'C',
  'children': []
}, {
  'text': 'A',
  'children': [{
    'text': 'A.3',
    'children': []
  }, {
    'text': 'A.4',
    'children': []
  }]
}];

function joinChildren(childrenArray) {
  return _.reduce(childrenArray, function(memo, o) {
    var already = _.find(memo, function(o1) {
      return o.text === o1.text;
    });
    return already ? (already.children = already.children.concat(o.children), memo) : memo.concat(o);
  }, []);
}

function joinChildrenRecursively(rootArray) {
  rootArray = joinChildren(rootArray);
  _.forEach(rootArray, obj => {
    if (_.isArray(obj.children)) {
      obj.children = joinChildrenRecursively(obj.children);
    }
  });
  return rootArray;
}

console.log(joinChildrenRecursively(tree));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it almost does what I want, but children Array consist now of Arrays and not of Objects. Is it possible somehow to change it?

Comment: @ConstantineGolub Sure, I've updated the answer with a possible solution. Is the result as expected? thanks!

Comment: Thanks, It works now but seems the max nesting level is 2, is it possible to fix it somehow?

Comment: @ConstantineGolub You would probably have to use recursion to construct the result. The solution would depend on the data structure that you're working with (how the nodes are within the array). Could you provide a complete example?

Comment: I've added the example of nested data to the description of issue

Comment: Could give an idea how to implement recursion that basis on your example of the script if it not difficult, of course? It works great except that issue

Comment: @ConstantineGolub I've updated the answer with a possible solution. This solution takes as a precondition that the array of nodes follows a special condition: each object at the same "level" in the array is at the same level in the tree (check the text names I used, it'd help you to clarify this precondition). Hope it helps or at least give you ideas on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you helped me a lot, really. 
Now I will handle with that.

Answer (score 1):

May be by utilizing the new `Object.values()` and with pure JS you might do as follows;

```js
var data =  [
      {
        'text':'parent 1',
        'children': [
          {
            'text':'children 3'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 2',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 3',
        'children': []
      },
      {
        'text':'parent 1',
        'children': [
          {
            'text':'children 1',
            'children': []
          },
          {
            'text':'children 2',
            'children': []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
   nested = Object.values(data.reduce((p,c) => (p[c.text] === undefined ? p[c.text] = {id: c.text, children: c.children}
                                                                        : p[c.text].children.push(...c.children),p), {}));
console.log(nested);
```

Comment: Thanks, right now it has a root for all tree. Is it possible to omit it?

Comment: @Constantine Golub You were right i have refactored my code. Check it up :)